# Regex for removing leading and trailing carriage returns and line feeds from a sentence

Tags: regex, string

Also is it possible to combine this with removing periods from within the string? The sentence may have spaces which I'd like to keep.

Comment: Do you also wish to remove spaces/tabs at the beginning/end of the string? Which language are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Search for

```
^[\r\n]+|\.|[\r\n]+$
```

and replace with nothing.

The specific syntax will depend on the language you're using, e. g. in C#:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^[\r\n]+|\.|[\r\n]+$", "");
```

in PHP:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^[\r\n]+|\.|[\r\n]+$/', '', $subject);
```

in JavaScript:

```
result = subject.replace(/^[\r\n]+|\.|[\r\n]+$/g, "");
```

etc...

Comment: Yours was sort of helpful, at least it sent me down the right path. For a text file and using Notepad++, the 'Find what:' is `\r\n` and the 'Replace with:' was a keyboard space.

Answer (score 1):

You can find:

```
^[\r\f]+|[\r\f]+$
```

and replace it with

```
''
```

For the periods you can find

```
\.
```

and replace it with

```
''
```

Some languages provide you with function what take a a group of regex and replacements and do the replacement in one call to the function. Like the PHP's preg_replace.

Comment: Is there any reason you're matching `\f` (form feed) instead of `\n` (line feed)?

Comment: I think it should be \n